# Regrouping and setGroupStartOpen when table is created

Tags: tabulator

On tabulator 4.4 I try to regroup a table. I have two Buttons. Button A groups by column1 and button B groups by column1 and colum2. This is working. 
I also want to set the groups shown open. But this seems not to work. Clicking button A all Groups should be collapsed and clicking button B groups by column1 should be expanded and groups by column 2 should be collapsed.

```
<body>
<div  id="example-table"></div>

 <div id="tabulator-controls"> 
            Group by:
             <button name="groupbya" id="groupbya" onclick="group1()">
               Column A
            </button>
            <button name="groupbyb" id="groupbyb"  onclick="group2()">
               Column A+B
            </button>
        </div>

<script  language="JavaScript">


var tabledata = [    
{id:1, column1:"GroupA", column2:"GroupA1", column3:"1", column4:"1"},
{id:2, column1:"GroupA", column2:"GroupA1", column3:"2", column4:"2"},
{id:3, column1:"GroupA", column2:"GroupA2", column3:"3", column4:"3"},
{id:4, column1:"GroupA", column2:"GroupA2", column3:"4", column4:"4"},
{id:5, column1:"GroupB", column2:"GroupB1", column3:"1", column4:"1"},
{id:6, column1:"GroupB", column2:"GroupB1", column3:"2", column4:"2"},
{id:7, column1:"GroupB", column2:"GroupB2", column3:"3", column4:"3"},
{id:8, column1:"GroupB", column2:"GroupB2", column3:"4", column4:"4"},
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata, 
    height:"500px",
   placeholder:"No Data Set",
   groupClosedShowCalcs:true,
    columns:[
        {title:"Column1", field:"column1"},
        {title:"Column2", field:"column2"},
        {title:"Column3", field:"column3", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcParams:{precision:0}},
        {title:"Column4", field:"column4", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcParams:{precision:0}},
    ]
});

function group1(){
        table.setGroupStartOpen(false);
        table.setGroupBy("column1"); 

}

function group2(){
        table.setGroupStartOpen([true,false]);
        table.setGroupBy(["column1","column2"]); 
}

</script>

</body>
```

1 . Afer loading the page when I first click button A it is ok but then clicking button B groups by column 1 are not expanded.

2 . Afer loading the page when I first click button B it is ok but then clicking button A groups by column 1 are not collapsed. They are expanded.

Answer (score 1):

The ***setGroupStartOpen*** Only counts when data is loaded into the table, not after the groupBy has been changed.

You have two options in this case:

You could either reload the data into your table which would then refresh the collapse state of the grouping

Or after changing the groupBy you could call the ***getGroups*** function on the table to get an array of [Group Componnents](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/components#component-group) and then iterate over it and call the ***show*** or ***hide*** function on each group in turn as needed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
As described in the documentation (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/group#manage) I thought it would be possible to Change the Start Open States after the table has been created.

Comment: Yes that's right. But as I mention in my comment above that effect is applied to the groups when they are first loaded into the table by the setData function. It is not a global expand or collapse on groups